# Sort a PHP JSON nested array in ascending order with usort according to a key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, usort

I have the following JSON array in my PHP

```
 {
    "responseHeader": {
        "type": "Places",
        "status": "200",
        "message": "Places fetched"
    },
    "Places_nearby": [{
            "place_name": "blueblue",
            "place_rating": "5"


        },
        {
            "place_name": "qwer",
            "place_rating": "10"


        },
        {
            "place_name": "mvb",
            "place_rating": "0.6"


        },
        {
            "place_name": "tyu",
            "place_rating": "25"


        },
        {
            "place_name": "erty",
            "place_rating": "1"


        },

        {
            "place_name": "Malabar Adukkala",
            "place_rating": "7"

        }
    ],
    "Google_places_most_rated": [{

            "place_name": "Malabar Adukkala",
            "place_rating": "5"


        },


        {
            "place_name": "Malabar Adukkala",
            "place_rating": "5"


        }

    ]


}
```

I need to sort the "Places_nearby" array inside it by increasing value of "place_rating".

What I did was decoding the JSON in my code,

```
json_decode($json,true)
```

And then using usort as follows

```
 function sortfunction($a, $b) {
return strcasecmp($a['place_rating'], $b['place_rating']);
```

}

```
usort($data['Places_nearby'], 'sortfunction');
```

But nothing happens.

How can I rewrite usort function, or do I want to write my custom function to sort the array? I thought that if PHP had some internal sporting mechanisms, that would be faster than other methods I can write.

P.S : I have already tried solutions that are mentioned in other SO answers, but they seems to be not working with my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002266/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: ...and a million others on SO... like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value/2699159#2699159

Comment: Sorry, but those millions of solutions are not working for my case. I already gave out the code that I tested. Sorry for the possible duplicate though.

Comment: Here is another that does work for your case and many, many others.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/2943403

Comment: If you have control over the structure of your input array and can put `place_rating` before `place_name` in each subarray, then you can simply use: `sort($array["Places_nearby"]);` because it will sort on the first element in the subarrays.  [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0ea7190fb2413e07a675a982fd707b8300d0733)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for sorting.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805539)

```
usort($array["Places_nearby"],function($value1,$value2){
  return  $value1["place_rating"]>$value2["place_rating"];
});
print_r($array);
```

Comment: @AshifShereef welome friend... :)